# How can I get the checkbox state in a Word form?

Tags: checkbox, ms-word, formula, formulas

I am using a ContentControl checkbox in my MS Word 2013 document (not Excel!). Now I'm trying to check in a formula, whether the checkbox is checked - or not. How can I do that?

Let's assume the checkbox' name is `MyCheckbox` I tried to check the state using

```
=MyCheckbox
=IF(MyCheckbox=TRUE; 1; 0)
=IF(INT(MyCheckbox)=1; "YES"; "NO")
```

But none of them helped me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I removed that tag. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a checkbox Content Control checkbox from Word's "Field language" using the Checkbox's "name" (i.e. title or tag).

You *may* be able to do this as follows:
Select the tab of the checkbox that you want to test 
Insert a bookmark (let's call it "check1")
Use the following nested field to test the value in your { = } field:

```
{ IF { check1 } = ccbcc 1 0 }
```

where you insert a checked checkbox content control directly into the IF field instead of the text "ccbcc"

I don't know of syntax that works with the { = } field's IF function.

However, it is possible that you will run into problems if you make the original checkbox control undeletable. When you do that, copies of the control generated when you execute the { check1 } REF fields also become undeletable, which is something you may also need to consider.

The only other way I know to do this that does not require VBA etc. at runtime is to set the checkbox up as a mapped content control, then use a plain text control mapped to the same element/attribute in the Custom XML part to do the comparison. That will always have a "true" or "false" result once the XML has been populated. So in that case you can compare your plain text control with the text "true". i.e. you still need an IF field with a nested content control, but only one control instead of two, and you don't need bookmarks:

```
{ IF thetextcontentcontrol = true 1 0 }
```

(where you insert your mapped text content control instead of "thetextcontentcontrol"

All the {  } need to be the special field brace pairs that you can insert on WIndows Word using ctrl-F9.

Answer (score 0):

Try `MyCheckBox.Value` in place of `MyCheckbox`.

Comment: I tried `=MyCheckbox.Value`, that throws a `!Syntax error, .`

Comment: 'If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
MsgBox ("The Checkbox is checked")
End If' Works for me using Word 2013.

Comment: I'm not using VBA, but just plain formulas in a field.